# Why does this regular expression match the second item and not the first

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following regular expression:

```
/BAR|FOO BAR/gi
```

And the following input string: "FOO BAR"

I would expect to get a match on "BAR", but I actually get a match on "FOO BAR". Why is this?

Comment: Please check my answer for a thorough explanation with demo code and how to match both `FOO BAR` and `BAR`.

Comment: Also, in future please specify the language you're using as regex's differ from language to language.

Comment: @SweetieBelle I noticed the behavior in Ruby and Javascript so I assumed it was common to regexes as a whole, but thanks for the tip and your detailed answer.

Comment: Ruby and JavaScript both use perl-compliant Regex, so yeah it will be the same as most other Regex implementations, but there are nuances between the languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regexes start at the beginning. It sees the `F`, and tries to match it against the `BAR` option. This of course fails. It then tries the `FOO BAR` option, and that seems to work, so it runs with that to find out if it works. Sure enough, it does, and so the match is `FOO BAR`.

Comment: @SweetieBelle Erm... Your example will attempt to match the F, fail, move on to the O, fail, next O, fail, space, fail, B, aha! Found the start of a match. A and R also match, that's the entire pattern, success!

Comment: @SweetieBelle: the regex engine examines each pattern at the first position in the string, then the second, etc. Read up on how regexes relate to regular automata.

Comment: @tripleee Read the below answer. I know plenty about how regexes work, but the *wording* of this answer isn't clear. Like many fast accepted answers, it doesn't explain what's really happening, it just gives a brief fly-by.

Answer (score 6):

### Regex will look for the pattern matched FIRST

First of all, let's examine your regular expression:

```
"/BAR|FOO BAR/gi"
```

What this searches for is either `BAR` or `FOO BAR` in the matched string. The flags (assuming [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) regex compliance) are 'global' and 'case insensitive':

1. **Global** flag means that the expression will attempt to return [all matches in the haystack](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching).
2. **Case insensitive** flag means that the expression will match regardless of case.

Let's try a few things in order to understand how matching works (*Note: I'm using `perl` because it's the most popular regex implementation, but these examples should work for your language if it's compliant*):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "FOO BAR";

if ($string =~ /FOO/) { print "1. True\n"; }  # 'FOO' matches in string
if ($string =~ /BAR/) { print "2. True\n"; }  # 'BAR' matches in string
if ($string =~ /foo/i) { print "3. True\n"; } # 'foo' matches in string, ignoring case
```

This will print `true` for all 3 statements ([demo](https://eval.in/44509)), demonstrating that `FOO`, `BAR` and `foo` are all valid matches with ignore case flag.

**So, why is your regex matching '`FOO BAR`' instead of '`BAR`'?**

Because, as documented, the parser will [try to match the earliest match in the string](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Matching-this-or-that).

```
my $string = "FOO BAR";

$string =~ /(FOO BAR|BAR)/;
print $1; # Prints 'FOO BAR'
```

Note that setting `/g` does not cause both to match, because it will try to match the ENTIRE rule `/FOO BAR|BAR/` as many times as possible, rather than match each side of the rule. As soon as '`FOO BAR`' is matched, it will stop trying to match in that part of the string and move on.

**What would you do if you wanted to match both `FOO BAR` and `BAR`?**

[This regular expression](https://eval.in/44542) would match '`FOO BAR`' and '`BAR`' given your input string:

```
my $string = "FOO BAR";

$string =~ /(FOO (BAR))/;
print "$1\n"; # Prints 'FOO BAR'
print $2;     # Prints 'BAR'
```

**Demonstration of the `/g` flag in context**

[This](https://eval.in/44541), using the `/g` flag, would match `FOO` and `BAR`:

```
my $string = "FOO BAR";

while($string =~ /(FOO|BAR)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

### To match what you're looking for...

[This example](https://eval.in/44588) would match `FOO` followed by space, `BAR` and `FOO BAR` for any input string.

```
my $string = "FOO BAR";

while($string =~ /((FOO\s)?(BAR))/g) {
    print "$1\n$2\n$3";
}
```

*Note: I have removed irrelevant flags from examples so as not to confuse future readers with similar issues.*

Comment: `/(FOO (BAR))/` wouldn't match `BAR` alone, though. It would only match it in the context of a `FOO BAR`.

Comment: Erm, no it wouldn't. It'd match `FOO`, an arbitrary number of spaces (including zero), then `BAR`. The entire match will be captured groups 0 and 1, `FOO` would be in capture group 2 and `BAR` in capture group 3. I must say your repeated use of parenthese to "capture" the entire match baffles me, considering you "know plenty about how regexes work". I'm thinking you're trying to deserve your name...

Comment: @Kolink If you want just a single space in all cases you'd match `\s` instead of `\s*` but that wouldn't match `BAR` without a preceding space. You could match the space, or match the space with `FOO`, or use layered alternates instead.

Comment: Also, without parenthesis you won't catch the entire match in a `while` loop: [with parenthesis](https://eval.in/44590), [without parenthesis](https://eval.in/44591). As the OP wants to catch `FOO BAR`, I'm allowing for that.

Comment: Okay, so Perl has some differences to what I'm used to. The point is, what if the search string were just `BAR`? `/BAR|FOO BAR/` would match it, but none of your own regexes would.

Comment: @Kolink If you wanted to match `BAR` alone, but not `FOO` alone you'd use `/((FOO)?\s*(BAR))/g` ([demo](https://eval.in/44623)) or `/((FOO\s)?(BAR))/g` if you don't want to match an arbitrary number of spaces but won't match `FOO` in `"FOO"` string ([demo](https://eval.in/44624)). `/BAR|FOO BAR/` fails to match the `BAR` in `FOO BAR` because it only wants one match.

Comment: @Kolink Understandable if you're used to PHP. In perl we use inline regexs (no need for `preg_match` etc) so we use `/` to delimit the edges of the entire regex construct and `()` to delimit matches.